# Show Error "Pt.slice is not a function" in react data table component in datatable with API

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-data-table-component

I am creating a React demo and showing an error in react-data-table-component in datatable. please review the below code and share your comments.

Show Error "Pt.slice is not a function" in react data table component in datatable with API
Image: https://prnt.sc/cpv_cFAlq5SD

```
import React, { useMemo, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from 'axios';
import DataTable from 'react-data-table-component';

export default function TableData() {
  const [loadingData, setLoadingData] = useState(true);
  const columns = useMemo(() => [
    {
      name: "Id",
      selector: row => row.id,
      accessor: "id",
    },
    {
        name: "Name",
        selector: row => row.firstName.lastName,
        accessor: "firstName.lastName",
    },
  ]);

  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
  async function getData() {
    await axios
      .get("https://dummyjson.com/users")
      .then((response) => {       
        setData(response.data);
        setLoadingData(false);
      });
  }
  if (loadingData) {
    getData();
  }
}, []);

  return (
    <div>
      
      <div className="w-full pt-5">
        {loadingData ? (
          <p className="w-full text-center">Loading... </p>
        ):(
        <DataTable
           columns={columns}
           data={data}
           selectableRows
           pagination
           paginationDefaultPage
          />
          )}
      </div>
      
      
    </div>
  );
}
```

Review this code

please check code and image and share your comment.
thank you

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue over the weekend and it turned out the data object path for one of the columns was incorrect, and because of that, the table was getting an `undefined` value for that column, and cannot call `.slice()` on a value that's not an array.

Comment: Can you please check the code and resolve the issue?